# How to change laravel database value before compare?

Tags: laravel, authentication, credentials

I have emails on the users table with upper and lower case, e.g

MyName@email.com
On the login I use email and password field.

I want to success login when the user send the email no matter upper or lower case e.g
if the user send: myNAME@email.com

I think to change all to lower case before compare.

Now I send the email field using overload credentials method on Logincontroller class

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = [
            $this->username() => strtolower($request->get($this->username())),
            "password" => $request->get("password")
        ];

        return $credentials;
    }
```

This convert the email sended to lowercase.

But how can I change to lowercase, database email value before compare?

Comment: I think it's better to be case sensitive. What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I thing the auth()->attempt(['username' =>$request->username, 'password' =>$request->password]) will do it for you and you don't need to be worry about Upper case or lowercase.